# What can I buy with M from a list L - recursive problem

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I'm learning how to solve recursive problems, I need your help on this one :)

I have an amount of money M and a list L of items (in a store for example).
The question is simple:
What are all the combinationss of items I can buy with this money? (how to build this recursively?)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Always be specific and make your best effort before asking, and don't treat Stack Overflow as a repository of tutorials. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be solved recursively as follows, using some C#-like syntax. The implementation is for clarity, not for efficiency, as new lists would be created on the fly.

```
struct Item
{
    public int Price; // value if the item
    public string Name;      // name for referential purposes
}

public void Rec(ItemList SelectedItems, int Money, ItemList RemainingItems)
{
    if (total value of all items in SelectedItems <= Money)
    {
        output SelectedItems as it is a feasible choice;
        if (RemainingItems is not empty)
        {
            let Item be some Item from RemainingItems;
            Rec(ItemSelection with Item, Money - Item.Price, RemainingItems without Item);
        }
    }
}
```

Let `SelectedItems` be an empty list and `RemainingItems` all items from the input. Call the function `Rec` as follows to enumerate the feasible choices.

```
Rec(SelectedItems, M, RemainingItems);
```

Answer (score 0):

For each item on the list there are two possibilities: buy or not buy. You can take each decision in one recursion step and in this way generate all possible subsets of L.

An item can only be bought, if you still have enough money for it. This cuts down the possibilities.